# How to save values of elemenents with same name to List

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have XML like this:

```
<SHOP>              
    <SHOPITEM>            
        <PRODUCTNAME>X</PRODUCTNAME>     
        <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>http://...img1.jpg</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
        <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>http://...img2.jpg</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE> 
    </SHOPITEM>                  
    <SHOPITEM>        
        <PRODUCTNAME>Y</PRODUCTNAME>         
        <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>http://...img3.jpg</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>
        <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>http://...img4.jpg</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>      
        <IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE>http://...img5.jpg</IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE> 
    </SHOPITEM>                                                                                                               
</SHOP>
```

And class like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to parse that XML to List of `Item` and save each `PRODUCTNAME` value to the property Name and all values of `IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE` elements to the List property `Images`.

I tried something like this but without success.

```
var items = from item in xmlDocument.Descendants("SHOPITEM")
              select new Item
              {
                  Name = item.Element("PRODUCTNAME").Value,
                  ImagesUrl =  
                      {
                         (from img in item.Descendants("IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE")
                          select item.Value.ToString()).ToList(),
                      }
              };
```

Comment: That is awesome. Just go ahead and do that. If you have concrete question (like "my XDocument - based code does not select 3rd `IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE` element") - edit your post and add you code you have problem with.

Comment: I just wanted fast send my question, after that I was editing my question and added my code.. Sorry guy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

List<Item>  itemList = (from e in xDoc.Descendants("SHOPITEM")
                        select new Item {  
                        Name = e.Element("PRODUCTNAME").Value,
                        Images = (from i in e.Elements("IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE")
                                    select i.Value).ToList()
                                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using Linq to Xml

```
var items = XDocument.Load(fname)
     .Descendants("SHOPITEM")
     .Select(s => new Item
     {
         Name = (string)s.Element("PRODUCTNAME"),
         Images = s.Elements("IMGURL_ALTERNATIVE").Select(x => (string)x).ToList()
     });
```